# seaborn dataframe question in python to groupby and count

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I have this data in my Python dataframe. The second column is gender and third column is car brand.
I would like the top five car brands from this by total count. And for those top five brands, I will need the seaborn plot for the brandwise count based on gender. ie. how many Male and how many Female.

```
# This prints all the brands. But I need only the top 5 though. 
sns.countplot(x = 'brand', hue = 'gender', data = dfCarBrand, palette = 'magma')
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions please?

```
Data
1   F   Ford
2   M   BMW
3   F   Skoda
4   M   GM
5   M   Audi
6   F   Audi
7   M   Mitsubishi
8   M   Hyundai
9   M   Honda
10  F   Renault
11  F   Renault
12  F   Audi
13  F   Skoda
14  M   GM
15  F   Audi
16  M   Audi
17  M   Mitsubishi
18  M   Hyundai
19  M   Honda
20  F   Renault
21  M   Renault
22  M   Audi
23  M   Skoda
24  M   BMW
25  F   Skoda
26  M   GM
27  M   Audi
28  M   Audi
29  F   Mitsubishi
30  F   Hyundai
31  M   Honda
32  F   Skoda
33  M   GM
34  M   Audi
35  M   Skoda
36  M   BMW
37  F   Skoda
38  F   Audi
39  F   Skoda
40  M   GM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to specify the top 5 in a graph, we will process the data to be used in the graph. Get the frequency count of the brand with `value_counts()`, and list the index of the series with the result as the top 5.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dfCarBrand5 = dfCarBrand[dfCarBrand['brand'].isin(dfCarBrand.brand.value_counts().head(5).index.tolist())]
sns.countplot(x='brand', hue='gender', data=dfCarBrand5, palette='magma')
plt.show()
```

[image]